# IOS Development under windows with a build server

Tags: ios, xcode, windows

I'm currently developing an IPhone app. I have two computers, one is an old, very slow macbook. The other is my current desktop. I have been developing the app under the macbook, but I was wondering if it were at all possible to set up my workflow so that the actual development could be done under my windows computer, and the app would automatically be compiled on the OSX computer. Would a build server, such as Jenkins, be the right tool for this? If not what would be the right tool to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like Xamarin to do cross-platform development? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx

Comment: React Native is another one of those newfangled frameworks where this is said to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would probably be no. I think some people may have managed to get some stuff working using virtual machines and the like to host OS X on windows, but there are a whole host of problems and issues to work around. As a general rule virtual hosting anything to try and do development almost invariably runs into performance and other issues.

There are a variety of CI servers you could host on the Mac to do builds, but if it's that old you're also likely to start running into hardware/IDE issues.

My recommendation would be that if you are serious about doing iOS development, upgrade your MacBook, either new, reconditioned or second hand.

Answer (score 0):

***Xamarin.iOS*** for Visual Studio allows ***native iOS applications*** to be ***developed and tested on Windows computers***, with a ***networked Mac*** providing the ***build and deployment services***.

May be you can take a look at this and try to do the same by yourself

or

Other than this Microsoft has introduced ***[Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/)*** which lets you ***debug,develop and deploy*** apps without help of any apple system but to sign and release you need Apple system though.

May be you can take a look at this and try to do the same by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You only have 2 options.

1. Upgrade your mac
2. Use xamarin to build your ios app but theres a bit of a learning curve to it.

I was going to say you can use Ionic which uses Angular and Cordova. But to even compile it, you would still need xcode.